# Running into issues getting embeds working on Discord.js 13

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
Error: Cannot find module '../rest/RESTManager'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Discord Music Bot\commands\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
- C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Discord Music Bot\commands\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Discord Music Bot\commands\embed.js
- C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Discord Music Bot\main.js
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aweso\Desktop\Discord Music Bot\commands\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:4:21)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
 requireStack: [
   'C:\\Users\\aweso\\Desktop\\Discord Music Bot\\commands\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\client\\BaseClient.js',
   'C:\\Users\\aweso\\Desktop\\Discord Music Bot\\commands\\node_modules\\discord.js\\src\\index.js',
   'C:\\Users\\aweso\\Desktop\\Discord Music Bot\\commands\\embed.js',
   'C:\\Users\\aweso\\Desktop\\Discord Music Bot\\main.js'
 ]
```

I've been trying to run embeds an this is the error i keep receiving not sure if there's an additional file i need to add or if theres a problem with the example embed I'm using since

```
const MessageEmbed = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
  name: 'embed',
  description: "example embed to test to see if it works lmao",

execute(message, args){

const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');

channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
}
}
```

This is the Example Embed I am using if there's an easier way to get it working, please do tell I've been looking into this problem for 3 days and keep receiving the same error.

#### Discord.js Version 13

#### Node.js Version 16.7.1

Comment: Strange, `RESTManager` is a private DJS file. Maybe it was accidentally deleted? Try reinstalling Discord.JS

Comment: Done but still receiving the same error

Comment: Appearently your node_modules are inside your commands directory, pull them out of there that should help

Comment: Please edit your question with the "other error"

Comment: It was fixed there was a small typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the `node_module` folder was in my `commands` folder. I moved the folder and then Embeds started working.